# Criterion#ignoreCase in newer versions of Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I just upgraded to Hibernate 4.1.10.Final (after first upgrading to 4.1.8.Final), but now this does not compile:

`Restrictions.eq("loginName", loginName).ignoreCase();`

This is due to the ignoreCase()-method no longer existing in the Criterion class. But, I can't find any documentation about this, do I need to replace it with something, or has it been rendered uneccessary since case is always ignored or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use instead

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike('prop', '%value%');
```

or

```
 criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike('prop', 'value', MatchMode.ANYWHERE);
```